# Can't access Settings -> Developer

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

In iOS 11.0 and prior we could access Developer settings to debug with different kinds of network statuses, but in 11.1 this option isn't there.

Does anyone know how to reenable it?

Is it even possible?

Is it gone for good?

Any official documentation on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

For a device that runs iOS 11.1 you have to download the Xcode 9.1 beta and pair the device with that Xcode version:

1. Connect the device to your Mac with a cable
2. Start Xcode 9.1
3. Open *Window -> Devices*
4. Select your device on the left. You will see an activity spinner and a yellow message:

> DEVICE is busy: Preparing debugger support for DEVICE.

When the device is ready, the **Developer** section in the Settings app will be there again.